# When should the fragment view model be created?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have always created the view model in the `onCreate` method of a fragment. I have also seen some other developers creating the view model in the `onCreateView` method. However today i used the Android Studio template for '**Fragment with ViewModel**' and the view model was created in the `onActivityCreated` method. Which approach is correct? If the Android Studio template is doing this in the `onActivityCreated` then surely there must be a reason behind this. Can any one shed light on the correct approach here?

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as it's done in/after `onCreate` and you reference the same `ViewModelStore` to prevent spawning duplicates.

Comment: It's safe to get the ViewModel in any lifecycle method, starting all the way in `onAttach`. When and how you observe data from it is important though, as you might run into lifecycle issues there.

Comment: @zsmb13 you cannot initialize a ViewModel with a SavedStateHandle in `onAttach`, only in `onCreate`; and you cannot initialize a ViewModel with a SavedStateHandle scoped to a NavGraph before "after `onCreate`" which is `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 3):

> If the Android Studio template is doing this in the onActivityCreated then surely there must be a reason behind this.

Guess the creators of the template missed the memo [that `onActivityCreated` will be deprecated](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha02).

> I have always created the view model in the onCreate method of a fragment. I have also seen some other developers creating the view model in the onCreateView method.

Theoretically you should be creating it in `onCreate`, but due to how the NavHostFragment shares the same `onCreate` dispatch as the regular fragments, you have to rely on `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` when you are using NavGraph-scoped ViewModels with a SavedStateHandle.

Therefore, a lazy initialization inside `onViewCreated` using `by viewModels` is your safest bet.